# How do you generate emacs/vi TAG file for OCaml?

Tags: emacs, ocaml, etags

I find that etags of emacs24 does not support OCaml, ctags of exuberant-ctags does not generate tags well for ocaml (identifiers are missing), and otags shipped with opam does not work on Ocaml 4.06, only supporting 4.01 version.

What's the most recommended way of generating TAG files to browse Ocaml codebase, especially for emacs?

Comment: Do you use custom built otags III, or any other tool?

Comment: How about the (maintained) https://ctags.io/ fork of exuberant ctags?

Comment: A more up to date `otags` can be found at http://askra.de/software/otags/. You might consider merlin, which is more or less the standard tool in the OCaml community (and has up to date versions that are opam installable).